# radio checked and change inner multiple dom css

Tags: html, jquery, css

Good day,

In a CSS file we change the styles of a label by using the following code:

```css
input[type=radio][name='rate']:checked + label {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="10" name="rate" value=10>
<label for="10" class="btn myLabel">
  <span>
    <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" class="rateImage" style="width: 80px"/>
  </span>
</label>
```

But how should I change the CSS of some element within it?

For example, I want to change the img size to become bigger.
I'm fine with either a jQuery or CSS code solution.

Comment: `input[type=radio][name='rate']:checked + label img {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example can work for you?

```
input[type=radio][name='rate']:checked + label img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```